# Redshift query results incorrect before VACUUM

Tags: amazon-redshift, vacuum

When Redshift uses an index to run a query (say counts), does it exclude counting the rows in the unsorted region?

I had copied a lot a data using the COPY command, but did not `VACUUM` the table afterwords. On running my query (involving joins with several tables), the results of the query were wrong - the newly copied rows in the unsorted region weren't counted.

Then, after vacuuming the table, the query began returning the correct results. Is this expected behavior, or is this a bug introduced by Amazon?

Comment: Amazon Redshift does not use indexes.

Answer (score 1):

Vacuuming won't have any effect on COPYed rows, which are effectively *inserts*. Vacuum physically deletes rows previously deleted with an SQL `delete` statement, which only *marks* the rows as deleted, so they don't participate in subsequent queries but still consume disk space.

Redshift is an *eventually* consistent database, so even if your `COPY` command had completed, the rows may not yet be visible to queries.

Running vacuum is basically a defrag, which requires all rows to be reorganized. This (probably) causes the table to be brought into a consistent state, ie all rows are visible to queries.